# Маска для TMaskEdit

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать маску для денег - запятая через каждые 3 разряда и в конце точка и 2 цифры. Пробовал, не получилось (надо, чтобы при незаполненных двух последних цифрах автоматически ставились нули). Может, есть какой-то компонент для работы с денежным форматом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можно сделать такую маску "999,999,999.99;1;_", и сразу забить её нулями. Потом при извлечении текста из MaskEdit убирать нули спереди.

Comment: Спасибо, так конечно неплохо. Но остаются запятые, даже когда соответствующие разряды не заполнены. Может, есть какой-то компонент для работы с деньгами?

Comment: Не вижу проблемы в том, чтобы при извлечении данных из MaskEdit редактировать их по своему усмотрению. Отсечение лишних нулей и запятых спереди делается в одной процедуре/функции.  

Если уж лень, то вот самый просто пример:   
  1. создаете переменную типа стринг  
  2. делаете цикл от 1 до количества символов в тексте MaskEdit и листаете каждый символ строки  
  3. если новая переменная пустая, а в текущем символе MaskEdit попадаются нули и запятые, то идем дальше.
  4. когда нули и запятые спереди MaskEdit заканчиваются, начинаете добавлять символы в вашу переменную.

Comment: Смотрите, какая проблема. Пользователь может ввести 35000, имея в виду конечно 35 тысяч, но в поле при маске заполняются сперва старшие разряды и получится 350,000,000.00.

Comment: А это уже неудобства маски, и с ними придется считаться.  
Я бы на вашем месте взял обычный Edit, и делал для него обработчики. Например, если пользователь не указал копейки, то при нужном условии (выход из комбобокса, передача управления другому элементу), к числу прибавляется ",00". Если пользователь указал копейку так ",1", то прибавлять к концу "0", чтобы получилось заветное ",10". И в таком духе...